# Memory usage by virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, virtual, multiple-inheritance

I have some classes (most of them are abstract, with **virtual** inheritance):

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual void f1() = 0;
        virtual void f2() = 0;
};

class B : virtual public A{
    public:
        virtual void f3() = 0;
};

class MyA : virtual public A{
    public:
        virtual void f1(){ ... }
        virtual void f2(){ ... }
};

class MyB : virtual public B, virtual public MyA{
    public:
        void f3(){ ... }
};
```

Now I use them:

```
B * object = new MyB();
object->f1(); //declared in A, imp. in MyA
object->f3(); //declared in B, imp. in MyB
```

Everything works fine, and the code is "good" for me (I can fast switch from `MyB` to `YourB` with changes in 1 line only).

### But my question is:

**How much additional memory it uses**, compared to the similar code listed below (same result, different structure)?

I'm not good with memory layouts/vTables, so please explain it to me in a simple way - I want to know, **if my application will spend more resources** (memory) and **if the executable will be slower**?

And I compare that code to that one:

```
class MyA{
    public:
        virtual void f1(){ ... }
        virtual void f2(){ ... }
};

class MyB : public MyA{
    public:
        void f3(){ ... }
};

MyB * object = new MyB();
object->f1(); //declared in MyA, imp. in MyA
object->f3(); //declared in MyB, imp. in MyB
```

The `sizeof(object)` returns 4 in both examples (Win x32, Visual Studio native compiler), but I'm not sure if it's authoritative here. Maybe it doesn't count something - I don't think that both samples are 100% equal.

Comment: Are you talking execution code size or memory/variable size?

Comment: Both of them are important for me, but the most important is the total memory size occupied in system when I run the application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where in memory is vtable stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905237/where-in-memory-is-vtable-stored)

Comment: This information is already given in surely many questions about vtables. This is a duplicate. Before asking a question, it is expected that you perform some research.

Comment: The size of the *vtable* may differ.

Comment: About the duplicate - I don't ask *where* the memory in vTable is stored (e.g. beginning of the object allocation) but how much memory will I spend. And the linked question did not give me the answer, maybe because my lack of knowledge/deduction (if so, sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation, but typically virtual inheritance will need:

- an extra pointer (or offset) for each virtual base class: the adjustment to convert (for example) `B*` to `A*` will depend on which other subobjects in the same object also derive virtually from `A`. I think this can be stored in the *vtable*, rather than the object itself, so that the overhead could be per-class rather than per-object.
- extra logic in the constructor and destructor, to determine whether or not the virtual base object needs initialising/destroying at that point.
- extra work for some pointer conversions, reading the stored pointer/offset rather than applying a compile-time constant.

For memory usage, you can measure the per-object overhead in your implementation by printing `sizeof (MyB)`. Any per-class overhead will probably be negligible, unless you have a huge number of classes.

Comment: If memory layout is interesting, gcc can do g++ -fdump-class-hierarchy

Comment: Thank you! So it will be per-class costs more then per-instance costs.

Comment: @PolGraphic: You should check that, if it matters to you. I'm just guessing what an implementation might do; there might be good reasons (e.g. performance) to put the adjustment in the object instead.

Answer (score 2):

Before I start, your concern is known as a *premature optimization*.  There are other concerns to worry about before size and space:  correctness and robustness.

Inheritance is usually implement through Virtual Function Tables, in essence, a table of addresses to functions.  So the amount of extra code space depends on the quantity of virtual functions.

Virtual functions are executed using a jump table.  A common practice is to load the Program Counter with the value in the Function Table.  This is usually 2 assembly instructions.

The amount of variable space for the function table may be less than the memory wasted by alignment padding in a structure.  The wasted execution time is less than the overhead to call a function.

**Edit 1:**
BTW, assembly instructions are usually executed in 1 microsecond or less.  So calling through a function table would take 2 microseconds.  Compare this with waiting for disk I/O or User I/O.

This is why it is a premature optimization:  optimizing before profiling.  Profile the entire code and attend to the bottlenecks before worrying about this waste of code and variable space.

Comment: Another nice answer (I can mark only one unfortunately, up-vote from me anyway). The comparison with I/O operations shows that it's "not a big deal". But my classes (MyB, MyA) can be the 3d engine classes (so they are called each frame, about 500 instances, 60 times per one second).

Answer (score 1):

For commonly used compilers, the overhead will be roughly as following

1. **Memory Overhead:** extra pointer to *vtable* for each parent class.
2. **Runtime Overhead:** each *virtual* method call will have indirections to find the **right** implementation of the method for actual type of the invoking object.

`sizeof(object)` returns 4 in both case because you are measuring **size of pointer to object**, not object itself. Pointer size is same no matter to which object it points.

Comment: Right, thanks. The memory overhead will be the same for 10 and 1000 instances of objects? I mean - the overhead is per class, not per instance?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, the memory overhead will be per-class.