# Is there a way to identify where the vPointers are located inside an object?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Is there a way to identify where the virtual pointers reside (by generating a mask or so) in the memory layout? (ex: Below code)

```
class D{//virtual functions}
class B{//virtual functions}
class A : public B, public D
{//virtual functions}
```

Comment: Possibly, but it is generally platform dependent, so you'd need to specify OS, compiler, version at least.

Comment: let's say SUSE Linux, gcc 4.3.4. But I'm searching for the idea behind rather than the implementation. Thanks.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905237/where-in-memory-is-vtable-stored or you can search for vtable and sort through the results.

Comment: You can reasonably guess that pointers to the virtual dispatch table will either be at the start or end of objects.  Using `offsetof` to check whether the first data member is at 0 or after a gap typically lets you infer which, though it's left as undefined behaviour by the Standard.  Tends to work on actual compilers though - anything you do with this information's undefined anyway, so I doubt you'd care....

Comment: Doesn't offsetof require types without virtual functions? Also biggest problem is dealing with the multiple inheritance. :)