# sizeof CRTP class implementing an interface

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, vtable, object-layout

i have a question about the `sizeof` an instance of a class that uses CRTP to implement an interface, as the following example.

```
#include <iostream>
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual int foo() {
        std::cout << "Interface\n";
        return 0;
        };
};

template <class Derived>
class Base : Interface
{
public:
    virtual int foo() override {
        Interface::foo();
        std::cout << "base\n";
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar2;
        }
    int bar;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    virtual int foo() override {
            std::cout << "Derived\n";
        Base<Derived>::foo();
        return bar;
    }
    int bar2;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(Base<Derived>) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(Derived) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

both `gcc` and `clang` output `16` as both the `sizeof(Derived)` and `sizeof(Base<Derived>)`, same result if i remove Base and implement it all in Derived as if they are all the same object [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/jnxsae7ce)

the question is, why does this happen ? does the compiler simply combine both `Base<Derived>` and `Derived` into a single class when it sees CRTP being used ? or am i missing something ? how does the compiler get away from storing the extra pointers to the vtables in Derived and shrink its size to have only 1 pointer size overhead ? and is there any hidden overhead with this approach ?

i was expecting that the compiler would put a pointer to vtbl of `Derived` then the int then a pointer vtbl of `Base` then an int then a pointer to the vtbl of the interface in `Derived` bringing its size to `40` bytes, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Virtual classes are generally implemented with a single vtable

Comment: This is unrelated to CRTP. Without multiple inheritance, there's at most one vtable pointer per class, you don't need more. Also alignment is involved, `Base` likely has a 4-byte padding at the end.

Comment: what is a "vtbl" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai virtual functions table, what stores the pointers to the functions to be called at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you print out the offsets of the data members `bar` and `bar2`, it becomes obvious what's going on:

```cpp
std::cout << std::bit_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&Derived::bar) << '\n';
std::cout << std::bit_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&Derived::bar2) << '\n';
```

This prints:

```
8
12
```

Judging by this, the layouts of the classes look like:

```cpp
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
[vptr         ] [bar  ] [     ] // Base<Derived>
[vptr         ] [bar  ] [bar2 ] // Derived
```

*Note: `vptr` is the pointer to the vtable of the object.*

Remember that there is only one vtable pointer per polymorphic base class. When the derived class is initialized, it replaces the `vptr` in the base class subobject. See also: [Where in memory is vtable stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1905237/5740428)

The last four bytes of `Base<Derived>` are padding, and `Derived` puts its `bar2` member into that padding.
This is allowed because `Base<Derived>` is a polymorphic class, and thus not standard-layout.
As a result, even though `Derived` has one extra data member compared to `Base<Derived>` it does not take up any more space.

If you added another `int bar3` member, it should take up 24 bytes.